Synchronising a MainActor isolated method during init and satisfying swift 6 concurrency
I have a LogManager singleton class that saves strings into an array for logging purposes. I want the first entry into the log to be some system information so it gets added during init
@objc
public final class LogManager: NSObject, @unchecked Sendable {
    
    static let sharedInstance = LogManager()
    private var _logs: [String] = []
    private let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "LoggingSerialQueue")
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        
        log(SysInfo.sysInfo())
    }
    
    func log(_ log: String) {
        serialQueue.sync {
            self._logs.append(log)
            print("****LogManager**** \(log)")
        }
    }
}

The problem is that the system information needs to be MainActor isolated as it calls MainActor isolated properties on UIDevice and several others.
private final class SysInfo {
    
    @MainActor
    static func sysInfo() -> String {
        UIDevice.current.systemName
    }
}

I do not want to force my LogManager to be MainActor isolated as it can be called from many different threads.
I know I can add the log call from init into a Task like this:
private override init() {
    super.init()
    
    Task {
        await log(SysInfo.sysInfo())
    }
}

but that actually leads to it being the second log in the array and not the first, when I initiate the class by sending a log command:
LogManager.sharedInstance.log(#function)


I'm wondering what's the best approach to take here?
Before Swift Concurrency and if I remove MainActor from the SysInfo, it all works as if it's synchronous.

Don’t mix DispatchQueue and async/await that is the first rule. Task will run after the init is done and before anything else. So default values will work but DispatchQueue is not compatible with async/await. Make the LogManager an actor and get rid of all the GCD.

init must be asynchronous for this to work. Since you do not want @MainActor, code not running on the main actor could be calling init, and then there needs to be an actor-hop. I know this is just pushing the problem down to the call site, but you gotta have this asynchronous bit somewhere.

@loremipsum I need this backward compatible with @objc so not sure actor can work here. I thought that's the point of using @unchecked Sendable, it let's the compiler know that i'm handling the sync logic?

idk about objective c, handling sync logic isn't the same as sync log is telling async/await "I am done, keep moving" even though DispatchQueue might still be waiting to get the work done. You could add a completion handler and then convert that completion handler to async await so you can "continuation.resume()" when the DispatchQueue is actually done

The idea is that the call site can actually continue. LogManager will add the log to the array in it's own time, but in sync so they all get entered in order that were fired.

If you can you can make the init async that way the log would truly get called on init vs init then Task

If you want the log messages to appear in the correct order, use your queue, e.g.:
@objc
public final class LogManager: NSObject, @unchecked Sendable {
    @objc(sharedInstance)
    static let shared = LogManager()

    private var _logs: [String] = []
    private let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "LoggingSerialQueue")

    private override init() {
        super.init()

        serialQueue.async {
            let message = DispatchQueue.main.sync {            // note, we rarely use `sync`, but this is an exception
                SysInfo.sysInfo()
            }
            self.appendToLog(message: message)
        }
    }

    func log(_ message: String) {
        serialQueue.async {                                    // but do not use `sync` here; why make the caller wait?
            self.appendToLog(message: message)
        }
    }
}

private extension LogManager {
    func appendToLog(message: String) {
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(serialQueue)) // make sure caller used correct queue
        _logs.append(message)
        print("****LogManager**** \(message)")
    }
}

private final class SysInfo {
    @MainActor
    static func sysInfo() -> String {
        UIDevice.current.systemName
    }
}

By using your queue, you are guaranteed the order of execution.
A few observations:

There is no reason why your log function should dispatch synchronously to your serialQueue. You are not returning anything, so sync is unnecessary and only introduces inefficiencies. Right now it might not make too much of a difference, but let us imagine that your logger was recording information to persistent storage, too; you would not want to measurably impact performance of your app because of your logging system.

The dispatchPrecondition is not needed, but it is good practice that a method dependent upon a particular queue be explicit about this requirement. That way, debug builds will warn you of misuse. It is a private method, so we know the potential misuse is limited to this class, but it is still a prudent defensive programming technique when writing GCD code. This is a NOOP in release builds, so there is no downside to programming defensively.

Unrelated, to the question at hand, but the convention for singletons in Swift is shared, so I have renamed that accordingly. But I also specified @objc(sharedInstance) so Objective-C callers enjoy Objective-C naming conventions.
But if you really want to keep the Swift rendition named sharedInstance, that is your call. But just appreciate that it is not the standard convention.



As an aside, you might consider retiring this custom logging manager entirely and use the native Unified Logging system. In legacy codebases, we would use OSLog. I know this does not apply in your case, but in iOS 14 and later, one would use Logger in lieu of OSLog.
The “Unified Logging” system offers many advantages over a custom logging systems:

You can right-click on a logging message and jump directly to the source that generated the log in Xcode 15+.

When running app on device, you can monitor logging messages in your macOS console app. This is useful in general, but invaluable when monitoring background tasks, monitoring on-device logging, etc.

In both Xcode and the macOS console, you can categorize your logging messages as debugging messages vs errors and filter accordingly.

You can even download on-device logging messages after the fact and review them inside the macOS Console app:
$ log collect --device --start '2024-06-12 08:00:00' —output Foo.logarchive
$ open Foo.logarchive



This will feel cumbersome at first (especially if you are stuck with OSLog for support on old OS targets rather than the much-improved Logger of iOS 14+), but the advantages are compelling, and once you start using it, you will not look back. Definitely consider “Unified Logging”.

Thank you for the tips and suggestions. I use this logger for users to email me detailed logs in case of issues. Can we do that with OSLog and Logger?

Unfortunately, your code produces a concurrency warning when accessing SysInfo.sysInfo() even though it is dispatched to the main queue. Is there a way to clear this warning (Error in Swift 6)?

That is interesting, because for me, with “Strict Concurrency Checking” set to “Complete”, I get no such warning. I wonder if there is some other change you haven't shared with us (such as storing this DispatchQueue.main in a variable). Regardless, to tell the compiler that you have dispatched this to the main queue, and therefore it is main actor isolated, just add MainActor.assumeIsolated {…} as shown here.

I created a new iOS project, pasted your code above into a new LogManager file, then added my SysInfo class from above to the bottom of the file. Changed the concurrency warnings to complete, and it gives the warning.

No warning in the latest Xcode with Swift 6, so that's fine.

Weird, because, again, I tested in both Xcode 15.4 and 16 (Beta 1) in both Swift 5 and Swift 6 modes. But assumeIsolated like that gist is a way to silence those sort of warnings while still ensuring concurrency-safety.

@Darren – I missed your question: “I use this logger for users to email me detailed logs in case of issues. Can we do that with OSLog and Logger?” … Yes, I believe you can use OSLogStore to do precisely that.


I do not want to force my LogManager to be MainActor isolated as it can be called from many different threads.

That's the heart of the matter: you need to stop thinking this way. This is exactly the kind of silliness that Swift Concurrency solves.
Get rid of all the DispatchQueue objects in your code (except for rare cases where you may need them in order to make an @unchecked Sendable type be genuinely thread-safe — but this is not actually such a case),  and adopt Swift Concurrency thoroughly and consistently. Then there are no "threads" and context switching ceases to matter. Just isolate LogManager to some actor and stop worrying.
Let us suppose, just for the sake of the example, that we isolate LogManager to the main actor. Then we can rewrite it like this:
@objc @MainActor public final class LogManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = LogManager()
    private let loggingActor = LoggingActor()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        Task {
            await loggingActor.log(UIDevice.current.systemName)
        }
    }

    func log(_ what: String) {
        Task {
            await loggingActor.log(what)
        }
    }

    actor LoggingActor {
        private var _logs: [String] = []
        func log(_ log: String) {
            self._logs.append(log)
            print("****LogManager**** \(log)")
        }
    }
}

Now when we call LogManager.sharedInstance.log(#function) in didFinishLaunching, we get:
****LogManager**** iOS
****LogManager**** application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)

which is the correct order. Everything is being ordered and will stay in the correct order, because it is backed by the full faith and credit of Swift Concurrency. If you happen to be on a different actor, not the main actor, and you happen not to be in an async method, then you will say
    Task {
        await LogManager.sharedInstance.log(#function)
    }

and you will still get everything in the correct order.
Here's the really nice part. Let's decide to take LogManager entirely off the main actor and isolate it to our own global actor:
@globalActor public actor LoggingGlobalActor {
    public static let shared = LoggingGlobalActor()
}

@objc @LoggingGlobalActor public final class LogManager: NSObject { // ...

What happens when we do this? Absolutely nothing! All our code keeps working the same way as before. And that's my point: your "it can be called from many different threads" completely falls away.

Thanks. I guess I didn't mention my other limitation, that I was hoping to keep iOS 12 support which means no Task use. I guess it's just time to byte the bullet and drop iOS 12 and maybe even objc

Indeed. But I wouldn't trust any back-ported async/await if I were you. Our team, maintaining an app for a massive corporation, with several hundreds of thousands of users, had no compunction about ceasing to support iOS 14 — and it was at that point that, with great relief, we converted to async/await (as well as many other iOS 15 innovations such as new-style formatters and attributed strings). That was a year ago; when iOS 18 comes out, we'll likely drop iOS 15 in its turn. I think iOS 12 support at this date is nothing short of insane.

Note, by the way, although I did not emphasize this in my answer, that my version of LogManager can adopt Sendable with no warnings / errors.

When you submit multiple unstructured concurrency calls with Task {…}, they will generally appear in the order they were submitted, but it is not guaranteed. As SE-0306 says, “This is conceptually similar to a serial DispatchQueue, but with an important difference: tasks awaiting an actor are not guaranteed to be run in the same order they originally awaited that actor.” You cannot rely upon actors and unstructured concurrency to ensure the order of execution.

Inspired by Rob's answer, codes here:
struct Platform {
    nonisolated(unsafe) static private var _systemName: String?
    nonisolated(unsafe) static var systemName: String {
        if let _systemName {
            return _systemName
        }
        let systemName: String
        if Thread.isMainThread {
            systemName = MainActor.assumeIsolated { UIDevice.current.systemName }
        } else {
            systemName = DispatchQueue.main.sync { UIDevice.current.systemName }
        }
        _systemName = systemName
        return systemName
    }
}

Then you can use Platform.systemName every where like swift 5 and below.
